# milliseconds timestamp in debezium postgres connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, strimzi

the segments are rolling over so quickly in our Kafka cluster, and it might be because we are producing records into the kafka cluster with a micro second timestamp, and Kafka expects it to be in milliseconds. Is it possible to change it to milliseconds in debezium postgres connector? Which config should I use to make data coming in milliseconds? Our kafka cluster is being unstable due to this issue.

config

```
   plugin.name: wal2json_streaming
   max.queue.size: 65536
   max.batch.size: 16384
   slot.max.retries: 20
   slot.name: {{ name }}
   database.hostname: {{ hostname }}
   database.port: 5432
   database.user: {{ user }}
   database.password: {{ password }}
   database.dbname: {{ name }}
   schema.whitelist: public
   table.whitelist:  public.outbox
   database.server.name: {{ server.name }}
   database.server.id: {{ server.id }}
   database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers: {{ bootstrapServers }}
```

Comment: Please provide full config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in debezium 1.1.0 version